# Align responsive text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to align the my icon's text to be on the same level. However, they are distorted when the window is resized bigger as shown in the fiddle. How can I make them to be beside each other?

Here's my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/whywymam/72qp7c6L/

My HTML:

```
                   <div id="btnTopInline">

                        <ul class= "nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">    
                                       <li>
                                         <div class="indivColl">
                                                <a href="signupLogin.php">
                                                   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBLqM.png" class="indi">
                                                   <p class="indit">Job Seeker</p>
                                                </a>
                                         </div>
                                       </li>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                       <li>
                                         <div class="empColl">
                                                <a href="signupLoginEmp.php">
                                                   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbaoj.png" class="emp">
                                                   <p class="empt">Employer</p>
                                                </a>
                                         </div>
                                       </li>
                                </div>

                            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>

                            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>

                            <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>

                        </ul>

                   </div><!-- end btnTopInline -->

                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-push-6 padBtnRight">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-login visible-xs">
                            <a href="signupLogin.php">
                                Job Seeker<br>Log In
                            </a>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                   <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-push-7">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-login visible-xs">
                            <a href="signupLoginEmp.php">
                                Employer<br>Log In
                            </a>
                        </button>
                   </div>

            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
```

Comment: Please, fix the image in your JSFiddle snippet.

Comment: Are you trying to get the burger icon to be on the same level as your menu items?

Comment: nope I want the texts beneath the two icons above the menu to be on the same line

Comment: If you correct all the errors in  your HTML, such as the divs in the uls, does the problem persist?

Comment: I don't see any errors in my HTML, could you please point them out to me?

Comment: You can use the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org) to detect errors in HTML pages. In this case, `ul` can't contain `div` and `button can't contain `a`